# Django TypeError <Page 1 of 8> is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, django, pagination

The error is occurred when I am trying to encode data into json. The error is due to pagination. I want json encoded data.

Here's the code that I am using for fetching the results from db and then encoding it into json

views.py

```
def pagination(obj, request):
    max = request.GET.get('max') if 'max' in request.GET else 1
    paginator = Paginator(obj, max)  # Show 25 contacts per page
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        return paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
        return paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        return ""

def folder_list(request):
    folders = UserFolder.objects.filter(creator=request.user).order_by('-modified_date')
    folders_dict = []
    for folder in folders:
        d = {}
        for k, v in folder.__dict__.items():
            d[k] = str(v)
        d["creator__first_name"] = folder.creator.first_name
        folders_dict.append(d)
    folders = Common.pagination(folders_dict, request)
    folders = json.dumps(folders)
    return HttpResponse(folders)
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: you could re-write this line `request.GET.get('max') if 'max' in request.GET else 1` as follows: `request.GET.get('max',1)` you can read more about here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get

Answer (score 1):

I have sorted out the issue. I have just added "object_list" while encoding the data in json like this :

```
def folder_list(request):
    folders = UserFolder.objects.filter(creator=request.user).order_by('-modified_date')
    folders_dict = []
    for folder in folders:
        d = {}
        for k, v in folder.__dict__.items():
            d[k] = str(v)
        d["creator__first_name"] = folder.creator.first_name
        folders_dict.append(d)
    folders = Common.pagination(folders_dict, request)
    folders = json.dumps(folders.object_list) #added .object_list
    return HttpResponse(folders)
```

Comment: <QuerySet ...> is not JSON serializable